# Cannot install SQL Server 2008 R2 express. Compiler returned error 0x8007005

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008, wmi

First off, I'm having a very similar issue to this StackOverflow post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31681386/sql-server-configuration-manager-wont-start-wmi-returns-error#

Installing SQL Server 2008 Express fails with an MOF Syntax error.

After running mofcomp on the sql files I get this:

```
Microsoft (R) MOF Compiler Version 6.1.7600.16385
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp. 1997-2006. All rights reserved.
Parsing MOF file: sqlmgmproviderxpsp2up.mof
MOF file has been successfully parsed
Storing data in the repository...
An error occurred while processing item 10 defined on lines 73 - 79 in file sqlm
gmproviderxpsp2up.mof:
Error Number: 0x80070005, Facility: Win32
Description: Access is denied.
Compiler returned error 0x80070005
```

This is on multiple Windows operating systems and the command prompt has been run as Administrator and System and still get the same result.

Any advice would be great, I have exhausted most of the Google searches however.